# Website links auto insert string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I made a new website for someone but when i tried to launch it live i had problems with links. 
 and also regular links get a specific "string".

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sites.com/style.css"> -> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sites.com/web/index.html/style.css">
<a href="http://sites.com/contact"> -> <a href="http://sites.com/web/index.html/contact">
```

After every change in wordpress editor the links are adjusted with one more  **/web/index.html/** .

In the wordpress database the links are good.

Comment: Your original `href`'s are missing the protocol. Also, [there's not enough information here to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I edited my post.
I don't know why every refence to my domaine gets this string.

Comment: Does this happen with a clean install of WordPress with default theme?

Comment: i just tested it and yes the problem persist.

Comment: Must be something with your hosting provider?

Comment: the old site had a similar structures with the /web/index.html/ example:sites.com/web/contact/index.html , site.com/web/home/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Siteurl & Homeurl in the Wordpress admin.

The siteurl is where the wordpress files are on the server.

> `sites.com/web`

The homeurl is `sites.com`

You can also set these in the
[Wordpress config file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_UR)

Comment: i defined the home and siteurl in wp-config and updated it in function.php but same problem. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)
And in wp-admin on settings/general the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) have that string  attached even thow in database the links are in the right way.

Comment: the Site Address (URL) can't be changed in wordpress admin and not even in the database. I tried several times and the adress is the same.